# Finding integer/lattice points (coordinates) inside a polytope/polyhedra?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, python, linear-programming

I am using Python but I wouldn't mind changing language. All I have gotten from my research are tools to *count* the number of (lattice) points inside a region given the equations for the planes that enclose it. Other tools are made to optimize a given function inside the polytope (linear programming).

How about finding the lattice points alone? For example, a function of the kind

```
latticePoints( 'x < 5 & x > 0' ) = [ 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Plus I am looking for something to work in the multivariate scenario (constrains on x, y, z, ...).

I am currently trying to solve this using [ppl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pplpy/0.7).

Comment: Do you want to **decide** whether there exist integer points inside a given polytope, or do you want to **enumerate** all integer points inside a given polytope?

Comment: Is the polyhedron convex?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The goal in to enumerate the points.

Comment: @rchilton1980 Yes it is convex.

Comment: Since convex, checking if a given point is inside/outside is I think straightforward (p is inside iff it's "below" each outwardly-oriented hyperplane). Enumerating all such points to test is maybe less straightforward, esp in high dimensions. Do you have suitable bounds on the coordinates? If you can make an aligned bounding "box", then you can enumerate all the points in that box, check each against the polyhedron, and only record/output the ones that pass the inside/outside check.

Comment: [Effective lattice point counting in rational convex polytopes](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jsc.2003.04.003) (2004)

Comment: @ViníciusGodim Did you manage to solve this problem with PPL? I would like to achieve the same.

Comment: @Siwel I didn't, sorry. Not that I know it's not possible.

Comment: I've had a suggestion from the authors of LattE to try out Normaliz (which has a Python library PyNormaliz). I'm yet to get this working, but it looks promising.